# Typescript react-redux configuring store error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

This is my code:

```
interface IState {
  userData: {
    name: string
    age: number
  }
  // companyData: {},
  // websiteData: {}
}
export const initialState: IState = {
  userData: {
    name: "Mark",
    age: 30
  }
  // companyData: {},
  // websiteData: {},
} 

const mainReducer = combineReducers({
  userData: userReducer
  // companyData: companyDataReducer,
  // websiteData: websiteDataReducer,
});

const configureStore = () =>
  createStore(
    mainReducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
  );

export default configureStore;
```

it generates this error which I do not understand:

Argument of type 'IState' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ userData?: { userData: any; } | undefined; }'.
Types of property 'userData' are incompatible.
Property 'userData' is missing in type '{ name: string; age: number; }' but required in type '{ userData: any; }'.

Comment: Where do you get this error?

Comment: First change I would do is: `const mainReducer = combineReducers<IState>`. Same for `userReducer`. You could also create types for each reducer, like: `UserState`, `CompanyState`.

Comment: so that didn't fix anything. The error is in the problems section of my terminal. The code compiles with errors and when I run it locally in browser get same error which I can close though.

Comment: Also, I don't think that you need to define root initial state. Preloaded state can be `undefined`. Check [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/initializing-state#recap)

Comment: Ok that fixed it, but I have always declared initial state when using create store. I don't think I understand how the typings for these different redux methods should be used.

Comment: I can't reproduce it based on the code you have given.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with my reducers, I was returning whole state instead of a slice of the state and that was messing everything up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).